# Pass list title as argument?

Tags: function-construction, export, files-and-directories, symbols

I have a function that works with a list and outputs it. Is it possible to also get the name of the list as an argument?
Right now my code is

```
exportPrognosisData[data_] := Export[StringJoin[ToString[HoldForm[data]], ".csv"], data]
```

But the resulting file name is the list and not its title.

Comment: Take a look at `SymbolName`, + its Possible Issues section. And at `HoldFirst` and friends.

Comment: I would've went the other way, `exportPrognosisData[data_String]:=Export[data<>".csv", ToExpression[data]];`

Comment: C**p, wrong tag and now I'm fully responsible for closing -.-

Comment: @Kuba, heavy is the mouse button of one who has a gold badge. ;)

Comment: @J.M. yep, lesson learned.